# Is dry ice safe to ingest?

Tags: nutrition, food-safety

I've heard that people use dry ice with drinks, but I'm wondering how safe that is. Since dry ice is carbon dioxide, isn't that dangerous?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to health.SE! We like to have clearly asked questions here, maybe with a bit more information like background of the question too. For example, maybe you're preparing a punch bowl for a dinner, and want to add dry ice to it or perhaps you're just curious about swallowing a cube of dry ice (bad idea). I've edited it to say what I think you meant to ask. Feel free to roll back any changes or make some more. I'll try to answer this by today.

Comment: I want to get answer because we having restaurant I want to put in to menu

Comment: The Chemistry Stackexchange has an answer on this one: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/788/what-is-the-effect-on-humans-of-using-dry-ice-and-liquid-nitrogen-as-food-additi

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the extreme cold of dry ice when it warms and becomes a gas again it gains volume rapidly. If it is in your stomach you will inflate to fatal levels. There are many cases where this has happened.
If you are drinking a beverage with dry ice in it make sure it has all evaporated (melted). It is used because of the 'cool' steam it gives of as it heats.

Supporting sources

> http://chemistry.about.com/od/dryice/f/Why-Is-Dry-Ice-Dangerous.htm

Similar thread

> http://www.instructables.com/answers/Is-drinking-water-with-dry-ice-in-it-dangerous/

The volume increase with sublimation is the same as liquid nitrogen:

> http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/9594000/Warning-over-liquid-nitrogen-drinks-after-girl-loses-stomach.html

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that this is not the average SE site. Here, [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/) are required, even if the answer has some correct information; otherwise it's unsupported opinion; answers here need to be based on *evidence*. The [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help section](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) will provide more information about the site, as will a quick look at the top voted answers and at meta. Again, welcome.